# grep, xml problem

Tags: xml, linux, grep

```
   @ubuntu:/tmp$ cat one.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <e2frontendstatus> 
     <e2snrdb>
      12.10 dB
     </e2snrdb>
     <e2snr>
      75 %
     </e2snr>
     <e2ber>
      0
     </e2ber>
     <e2acg>
      99 %
     </e2acg>
    </e2frontendstatus>
   @ubuntu:/tmp$ sed -n -e 's/.*<e2ber>\([0-9][0-9]*\)<\/e2ber>.*/\1/p' one.xml 
   @ubuntu:/tmp$
```

I want to get the value betwen . But it's not working, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work because you have newlines in there... this will be doable with sed or awk, I'm sure, but would probably be happier in perl... do you have that available?

Comment: The problem is that sed applies regular expressions to one line at a time. Since the <e2ber> and </e2ber> are on different lines they are not matched by the expression.

Can you change the file format to something like <e2ber value="0" />?  Then you might be able to identify the line more easily.

Comment: The other question we should ask is your exact requirement. I understand you have limited resources, so you're not going to fully parse the XML, so your robustness is going to be limited. You can at least count on the XML file not doing anything too crazy, I hope.

Comment: So, this is a linux satellite receiver on which I want to run my "save signal strength to a cvs file every hour" script. Signal stats come from the webinterface (ip/web/one.xml). The file format is fix, I can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What value are you looking for? Do you know that Linux's grep has an "After context" and "Before Context" command line parameters? That might be the easiest way of pulling of the information you're looking for.

For example, if you're trying to get the value after the line , you could do something like this:

```
$ grep -A1 "<e2ber>" | tail -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Processing xml with regular expressions is not a very good idea, you might want to look into a command line tool like xmlstarlet to do this extraction.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//e2ber" one.xml
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I run this little command on an embedded system (satellite receiver), where is not possible to run xmlstarlet (which is a very nice tool) :/ .

All other linux command is available, grep, sed..

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `grep -A` option mentioned in the above answer, and the Unix command `tr` on your system, you can make something reasonably robust.

This command should get the appropriate value:

```
grep -A2 '<e2ber>' one.xml | \
    tr -d '\n' | \
    sed -n -E -e 's/.*<e2ber>[[:blank:]]*([0-9][0-9]*)[[:blank:]]*<\/e2ber>.*/\1/p'
```

This should work whether the XML file is formatted as `<e2ber>0</e2ber>`
or as

```
<e2ber>
    0
</e2ber>
```

The grep will grab enough lines to include the closing tag, the tr will make this one long line, and the sed will extract the value. I've updated the regular expression in the sed to ignore whitespace around the value.

This may still have problems if the XML file is double spaced -e.g.

```
<e2ber>

0

</e2ber>
```

You can get round this by running the XML file through `tr -s '\n'` beforehand. This will compact multiple newlines into a single newline.